# What are the advantages of using Navigation Drawer with Activities VS with Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to implement a Navigation Drawer in my app but I am conflicted on whether  I should use it with Fragments or with Activities (see image below for more details).

Is there any real advantages or disadvantages between the two or is it just a matter of preference?

**Edit:**

Just to clarify my question:

1. In the case of using Activities instead of Fragments;

When I select "Import" that will open an Activity and not a Fragment and if I select "Gallery" it will open an Activity with contents for gallery item etc. and so on for the other items in the Drawer window.

2. In the case of using Fragments instead of Activities;

If I choose from any of the Items in the Drawer window it will open their contents in Fragments for each Item selected instead of starting new Activities for each selction.

[image]

Comment: If you open a new Activity, you lose the Navigation Drawer. A drawer should be used when all Fragments are related to some "top-level" view.

Comment: @cricket_007 So basically if I used the Drawer with Activities I would have to create a new instance of it in each NavigationDrawer item's Activity page?

Comment: I think so. You'd have to call `setContentView`, and you'd lose the reference to the other drawer.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember Fragments need an Activity. You always have one minimum when using Fragments.

If you are talking about to use like main element in the most cases is best use fragments because you have more flexibility UI.

The performance would be better if you have 3 activities and 10 Fragments or have 13 Activities? Think about it, the navigation within the App would be the big challenge but it's just about using the right flow in your application.

**Edit:**

For instance:

Drawer With Activities instead of Fragments

If you were to use NavigationDrawer without Fragments then it would be best to keep the NavigationDrawer instance in a single Activity and when you navigate the app by choosing from the items in the NavigationDrawer then each of those Activities that are started should not implement the NavigationDrawer but instead should implement the back button to Navigate back to the "Main"/single Activity that the NavigationDrawer was implemented in.

Note: If you do want to implement the NavigationDrawer in multiple Activities you would have to recreate a new instance of the NavigationDrawer in every Activity that you desire to display it.

I suppose this would be a disadvantage vs using Fragments whereas if you used a fragment you wouldn't need many instances of the drawer you would only need one.

Drawer With Fragments instead of Activities

If you use the NavigationDrawer with Fragments then the drawer should be implemented in a single Activity and when each drawer item is selected, their contents are displayed in each of their very own Fragments(which is called inside of the central Activity which manages all the Fragment instances)